# Deserialize XML into two classes

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Data>
    <SerialNumber>123321</SerialNumber>
    <AFCommand>ALL</AFCommand>
    <SqlServerAdress>./test123</SqlServerAdress>
    <Mode>SE</Mode>
    <Prerequsites>Prerequsites check failed</Prerequsites>
    <Connection>Connection check failed</Connection>
</Data>
```

and I want to deserialize it into two classes:

```
    [XmlRoot("Data")]
public class ConsoleMessages
{
    [XmlElement("Prerequsites")]
    public string prerequsitesCheckFailed { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Connection")]
    public string connectionFailed { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
 [XmlRoot("Data")]
    public class InstallationAdditionalData
    {
        [XmlElement("SerialNumber")]
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("AFCommand")]
        public string AFCommand { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("SqlServerAdress")]
        public string SqlServerAdress { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Mode")]
        public string Mode { get; set; }
    }
```

using this code:

```
 private void DeserializeAdditionalData(string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InstallationAdditionalData));
        StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(filename);
        XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
        try
        {
            this.InstallationAdditionalData = (InstallationAdditionalData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConsoleMessages));
            var a = (ConsoleMessages)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Environment.Exit(11);// błąd w czasie odczytu xml
        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
```

With this effect:

- InstallationAdditionalData is deserialized correctly.
- ConsoleMessages is always null

Do I need to rewind StreamReader/XMLReader? If yes how. Intellisense does not return me anything like:
`fs.Position or reader.Position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to rewind the stream to be able to deserialize it again.

`StreamReader` uses `FileStream` internally, if you pass it a filename. Easiest solution is to create the `FileStream` yourself, and pass it in.

```
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);

//...

fs.Position = 0;
reader.DiscardBufferedData();

//...
```